# Short form for class function without arrow function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In React I create return null components - https://github.com/joshwcomeau/return-null - so I do this:

```
class Blah extends Component {
    render = () => null
}
```

Now I am using an arrow function here only for simplicity's sake. This causes Babel to do extra overhead (unnecessarily binding) which is not needed.

Is there a shot form of class methods that just return without arrow binding? Like this:

```
class Blah extends Component {
    render() null
}
```

Comment: Why not just do `this.render = null` (inside the constructor)? Or leave the arrow function as is? The alternative seems to be more verbose... `render() { return null }`

Comment: What extra overhead to you think Babel is being made to do?

Comment: I don't think Babel does bind arrow functions that don't use `this`.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi for that insight!

Comment: @torazaburo I thought Babel was doing a bind in constructor.

Comment: @evolutionxbox because the method needs to bea function, it needs to return when called. Doing `this.render = null` wouldn't that be just a property on the class? Not a method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign `() => null` to some variable and use it whenever you want to have null component, for example:

```
const rnull = () => null;

class Blah extends Component {
    render = rnull
}
```

There isn't any syntax to make this even simpler or shorter.